# Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: express

помогите понять, почему выдает такую ошибку, когда нажимаю на удалить:

```
   Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

я только учусь. может в коде что-то.
 использовал `Mongoose` :

```
router.delete('/contacts/:id', function(req,res){

  Contacts.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
      if(err){
          res.send({message: "Error" + err})
      }
      user.remove(function(err){
          if(err){
              res.send(err)
          }
          res.send({message: "Delete"})
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Судя по всему, mongoose не может найти пользователя (user) по этому id, так как пользователя с таким id нет.

Comment: у объекта user не найдено свойство remove, которое у вас является  ссылкой на функцию.